# Install bashmark on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bash, bashrc

I followed the instructions at this page: http://www.huyng.com/projects/bashmarks/
to install bashmark on ubuntu.
I have not understood what the guide mean with "add source ~/.local/bin/bashmarks.sh from within your ~.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file". What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Do you now have a `~/.local/bin/bashmarks.sh` file?

Comment: Yes I have found it

Answer (score 1):

It asks you to open a terminal and open either `~/.bash_profile` or your `~/.bashrc` and type the following at the end of the file:

```
source ~/.local/bin/bashmarks.sh
```

This will execute the contents of `~/.local/bin/bashmarks.sh` in the current shell everytime you start a new instance of bash.

See this question for more on what source does:

- [What does source do?](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)